# WPF Listview Gridview styling column header presenter

Tags: wpf, styles

I am making a style for gridview in WPF which consists of several parts, currently I am stuck with the column headers part

I made a style for GridViewColumnHeader but now I need a style for its container

is there a part similar to "DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter" which is a wrapper for all of the columns?

Any help where to find the parts of the control? I want to find the name of that part and the default template for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reason why [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is very good.

You get Snoop to identify the element your looking for

[image]

Guess it's `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` what your looking for.